# Hash returns different results for the same input

Tags: java, hash

I can't get `MessageDigest` to output the same hash even using the same string 3 times in a row. I've simplified the code to the basics and this behaviour still persists.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class foo {

    private static byte[] hashPass(String _pass) {  
        MessageDigest mDigest;
        try {
            mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("[" + e.getMessage() + "] Unable to create message digest");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return mDigest.digest( _pass.getBytes("UTF-8") );
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("[" + e.getMessage() + "]");
            return null;
        }
    } //private boolean hashPass(...)

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hash1: " + hashPass("string"));
        System.out.println("Hash2: " + hashPass("string"));     
        System.out.println("Hash3: " + hashPass("string"));     
    }

}

//Outputs:
//Hash1: [B@7852e922
//Hash2: [B@4e25154f
//Hash3: [B@70dea4e
```

The strange thing is that it outputs the same outputs on every rerun - this implies that the internal state changes every time in the same way? Does it use salt or other inputs that I'm not aware of and should specify/use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hashPass()` method returns a `byte[]` array and in java arrays don't have a meaningful `toString()` representation. To display the elements of the array use [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hashPass("string")));
```

which will print:

```
[71, 50, -121, -8, 41, -115, -70, 113, 99, -88, -105, -112, -119, 88, -9, -64, -22, -25, 51, -30, 93, 46, 2, 121, -110, -22, 46, -36, -101, -19, 47, -88]
```

or convert the `byte[]` array to hex representation:

```
byte[] bytes = hashPass("string");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

which will print:

```
473287F8298DBA7163A897908958F7C0EAE733E25D2E027992EA2EDC9BED2FA8
```

Comment: That does indeed work.. that is so strange. I didn't print them at first, just compared with `==`, and it still didn't determine them as the same. I guess I will have to use `Arrays.equals`?

Comment: @areuz yes or `Arrays.deepEquals()` if you have two dimensional array.

Comment: @Karol.Dowbecki Thanks, still getting the hang of this after a switch from C++ :D